# Jquery hide first 12 elementes, show next 12 elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

what i am trying to do is make the first 12 elements hidden and show the next 12 elements.

```
//this is dynamic loaded content
<div class="inner-content">
     <div class="front-pro">1</div>
     <div class="front-pro">2</div>
     <div class="front-pro">3</div>
     <div class="front-pro">4</div>
     <div class="front-pro">5</div>
     <div class="front-pro">6</div>
     <div class="front-pro">7</div>
     <div class="front-pro">8</div>
     <div class="front-pro">9</div>
     <div class="front-pro">10</div>
     <div class="front-pro">11</div>
     <div class="front-pro">12</div>
     <div class="front-pro hidden">13</div>
     <div class="front-pro hidden">14</div>
     ..... etc (200 divs more)
</div>
<div onclick="SearchNext();">next</div>
```

This is my javascript/jquery:

```
function SearchNext(){
 var first = $('.inner-content').children('.front-pro:hidden:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(12)').hide();
    first.nextAll(':lt(12)').show();
}
```

It works one time, after it stops working. (and it skips number 13)
i want to have 12 new elements visible with each Next click and hide the previous.

**UPDATE - this is my end result that works perfectly**
[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/v7a4308e/1/)

Thanks to Alex Char

**PHP** for creating page numbers, you could do this also with javascript

```
//$counter is search results
    $x = 1; 
    $Pnumbers = '';
    while($x <= ceil($counter/12)) {
        if($x == 1){ $ecl = 'bold'; } else{ $ecl = ''; }
       $Pnumbers .= ' <span class="number '.$ecl.' numbering" onClick="GoTo('.$x.');">'.$x.'</span> ';
        $x++;
    } 

    if($counter > 12){ echo'<div class="page-numbers">
    <span class="prev number" onclick="GoTo(\'prev\')">Prev</span>
    '.$Pnumbers.'
    <span class="next number" onclick="GoTo(\'next\');">Next</span>
    </div>'; }
```

**Javascript:**

```
function GoTo(nn) {
      var nng = parseInt($('.page-numbers .numbering.bold').text());
     if(nn == 'next'){
        nn = nng+1; 
     }if(nn == 'prev'){
         nn = nng-1; 
     } 
    //get all child elements with class front-pro 
    //of element with class .inner-content
    var childElems = $(".inner-content .front-pro");
    var totalpages = Math.ceil(childElems.length/12);
    //iterate through the elements
    var first = (nn-1)*12;
    var last = first+11;
    childElems.each(function(i, el) {

      //show the elements that match the criteria removing css class
      if (i >= first && i <= last) {
        $(el).removeClass('hidden');
      } else {
        //hide rest
        $(el).addClass('hidden');
      }
    });

    if(nn > 1){ $('.page-numbers .prev').show(); }else{ $('.page-numbers .prev').hide(); }
    if(nn < totalpages){ $('.page-numbers .next').show(); }else{ $('.page-numbers .next').hide(); }
    $('.page-numbers .numbering').removeClass('bold');
    $('.page-numbers .numbering:eq('+(nn-1)+')').addClass('bold');
  }
```

**CSS:**

```
.front-pro.hidden{ display:none !important; }
.prev {  display: none; }
.page-numbers .number{
background: #ff0000;  }
.page-numbers{ text-align:center; }
.page-numbers .number.bold{ font-weight:bold; background:#000; }
.page-numbers .number:hover{ background:#000; cursor: pointer; }
```

Make sure that the first 12 divs do not contain the "hidden" class, all the divs that come after should have "hidden" in there class

Comment: Glad that I helped you. Looks pretty good. One suggestion. Instead of using only one function(`GoTo`) think about to use smaller functions or  you can use Revealing Module Pattern as I did in my example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I change a bit the implementation to support and previous. I use a css class to hide content.

```js
function searchNext() {
  $('.inner-content').children('.front-pro:lt(12)').addClass('hidden');
  $('.inner-content').children('.front-pro:gt(11)').removeClass('hidden');
  $(".next").hide();
  $(".prev").show();
}

function searchPrev() {
  $('.inner-content').children('.front-pro:lt(12)').removeClass('hidden');
  $('.inner-content').children('.front-pro:gt(11)').addClass('hidden');
  $(".next").show();
  $(".prev").hide();
}
```

```css
.front-pro.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.prev {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner-content">
  <div class="front-pro">1</div>
  <div class="front-pro">2</div>
  <div class="front-pro">3</div>
  <div class="front-pro">4</div>
  <div class="front-pro">5</div>
  <div class="front-pro">6</div>
  <div class="front-pro">7</div>
  <div class="front-pro">8</div>
  <div class="front-pro">9</div>
  <div class="front-pro">10</div>
  <div class="front-pro">11</div>
  <div class="front-pro">12</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">13</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">14</div>
</div>
<div class="next" onclick="searchNext();">next</div>
<div class="prev" onclick="searchPrev();">prev</div>
```

I create a general solution after your comment with next and previous(I use step 3 for demo purposes but you can use what ever you want):

```js
var pager = (function() {
  /*declare private variables*/
  var first = 0,
    last = 2,
    step = 3;

  function searchNext() {
    //next function
    //increasing first and last variables
    first += step;
    last += step;
    pagerHelper();
  }

  function searchPrev() {
    //previous function
    //decrease first and last variables
    first -= step;
    last -= step;
    pagerHelper();
  }

  function pagerHelper() {
    //get all child elements with class front-pro 
    //of element with class .inner-content
    var childElems = $(".inner-content .front-pro");
    //iterate through the elements
    childElems.each(function(i, el) {
      //show the elements that match the criteria removing css class
      if (i >= first && i <= last) {
        $(el).removeClass('hidden');
      } else {
        //hide rest
        $(el).addClass('hidden');
      }
    });
    nextPreviousToggle(childElems.length);
  }

  function nextPreviousToggle(maxEle) {
    //here the code is to show/hide next/previous buttons
    if (last >= maxEle) {
      $(".next").hide();
    } else {
      $(".next").show();
    }
    if (first === 0) {
      $(".prev").hide();
    } else {
      $(".prev").show();
    }
  }
  return {
    searchNext: searchNext,
    searchPrev: searchPrev
  }
})();
```

```css
.front-pro.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.prev {
  display: none;
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner-content">
  <div class="front-pro">1</div>
  <div class="front-pro">2</div>
  <div class="front-pro">3</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">4</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">5</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">6</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">7</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">8</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">9</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">10</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">11</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">12</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">13</div>
  <div class="front-pro hidden">14</div>
</div>
<span class="next" onclick="pager.searchNext();">next</span>
<span class="prev" onclick="pager.searchPrev();">prev</span>
```

**References**

[:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

[:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

Comment: this works, but i got over 200 front-pro divs, i would like to go to the next 12 with each click, now it shows everything

Comment: I updated my post using a part of your javascript - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7a4308e/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
$('.inner-content').children().each(function (i, x) {
    if (i < 12) // Hide First 12 i.e 0-11
        $(x).addClass('hidden');
    else if (i < 24) // Show Next 12 i.e 12-23
        $(x).removeClass('hidden');
})
```

Also make sure you have css rule defined as

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: this hides everything

Answer (score 1):

You use the following code to handle any number of divs,

```
var x = $(".inner-content div").hide();

$("div:contains(next)").click(function() {
  var cnt = $(this).data("cnt") || 0;
  if((cnt * 12) > x.length){ cnt = 0; }
  x.hide().filter(":eq("+ (cnt * 12)  + "), :lt(" + ((cnt * 12) + 12) + "):gt(" + (cnt * 12) + ")").show();
  $(this).data("cnt", ++cnt);
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3rk53h7L/1/)

Comment: this is the best way to do it thanks a lot! Do you also know how to do a Previous button?

Comment: @Vazzilly Yeah but ask a new question for that. So that it would get attention from other experts here. Also that would help the future visitors also. Lets keep this post unpolluted. :)

Comment: [New post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292025/jquery-hide-first-12-elementes-show-next-12-elements-previous-and-next)

Comment: @Vazzilly Its 12:15 am here in india. Brain slept already. Try to get soln from others. If not I will give you a soln for that tomo, the same time. :)