# Jquery hide first 12 elementes, show next 12 elements Previous and Next

Tags: javascript, jquery

what i am trying to do is make the first 12 elements hidden and show the next 12 elements and reverse, its like a next page and previous page in a search result.

Got this code from [Jquery hide first 12 elementes, show next 12 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289573/jquery-hide-first-12-elementes-show-next-12-elements)

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3rk53h7L/1/)

```
  <div class="inner-content">
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">151</div>
      <div class="front-pro">152</div>
      <div class="front-pro">152</div>
etc...
    </div>

    <div>next</div>

    var x = $(".inner-content div").hide();

    $("div:contains(next)").click(function() {
      var cnt = $(this).data("cnt") || 0;
      if((cnt * 12) > x.length){ cnt = 0; }
      x.hide().filter(":eq("+ (cnt * 12)  + "), :lt(" + ((cnt * 12) + 12) + "):gt(" + (cnt * 12) + ")").show();
      $(this).data("cnt", ++cnt);
    });
```

This code works but i want to reverse it with a previous button

Comment: I think replacing the +12 to -12 and ++count to --count shld get you that functionality..

Comment: You can check my updated answer that covers OP requirements. [Jquery hide first 12 elementes, show next 12 elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289573/jquery-hide-first-12-elementes-show-next-12-elements/36290005#36290005)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

**JQuery**

```
$(".next").click(function() {
  var childEls = $('.inner-content').find('.front-pro').not(".visible") ; // array
  var count = 1;

  $.each(childEls, function() {
    if (count <= 12) {
        $(this).toggleClass('visible');
    }
    count++;
  });
});

$(".prev").click(function() {
  var count = 1;

  $($('.inner-content').find('.visible').get().reverse()).each(function() { 
      if (count <= 12) {
        $(this).toggleClass('visible');
    }
    count++;
  });
})
```

Here's a link to demonstrate - [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rk53h7L/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines would have been my approach.
Since you retrieve all of the elements that you are working with in x.
I would look into the Jquery Slice() method where you can ask for a subset of the selector results. Not complete per say, but I hope it helps you get to where you want.

```
var x = $(".inner-content div").hide();
var $nextdiv = $("div:contains(next)");
var $previousdiv = $("div:contains(previous)");

var pageNum = 0;
var numOfPages = Math.ceil(x.length / 12);


$nextdiv.click(function() {
  if (pageNum < numOfPages) {
    var toshow = x.slice(pageNum * 12, pageNum * 12 + 12).show(); // show next 12
    x.not(toshow).hide(); // hide all others
    pageNum++;
  }
});


$previousdiv.click(function() {
  if (pageNum > 0) {
    pageNum--;
    var toshow = x.slice((pageNum - 1) * 12, (pageNum - 1) * 12 + 12).show(); // show last pages 12 records
    x.not(toshow).hide(); // hide all others
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3rk53h7L/5/